# Laravel array to string convension

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, sqldatatypes

Sorry Im new to Laravel and trying to save to the database from a form that i build with **[laravel-admin](https://laravel-admin.org/)** . Im trying to save an checkbox (so i think its an array) to the database with string field but the error "array to string conversion" is appearing. I've tried changing the field type but the same error even if i put it int

i have two tables
the first one is Cities

;
and the second one is City options

;

i want to select multiple options from option_name field into city_available_options by a checkbox,

but this problem just destroy me for two days now_ please help me guys;

city model code:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;
use App\Admin\Controllers\CountryController;
use Encore\Admin\Traits\ModelTree;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class City extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
use ModelTree;
public function cityCountry()
 {return $this->hasOne(Country::class,'id','country_id');}
public function city_cityoption_relation()
{return $this->belongsToMany(city_option::class);}
}
```

city options model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Encore\Admin\Traits\ModelTree;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class city_option extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class);
    }
}
```

cityController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\city_option;
use App\Models\Country;
use Encore\Admin\Controllers\AdminController;
use Encore\Admin\Form;
use Encore\Admin\Form\Field\Id;
use Encore\Admin\Grid;
use Encore\Admin\Show;

class CityController extends AdminController
{
    /**
     * Title for current resource.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = 'City';

    /**
     * Make a grid builder.
     *
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new City());
        $grid->column('id')->color('#FBE7C6');
        $grid->column('cityCountry.country_name',__('City Video'))->color('#D5B741');
        $grid->column('city_information',__('City information'));
        $grid->column('city_video',__('City Video'));
        $grid->column('city_voice_information',__('City Voice record'));
        $grid->column('city_available_options',__('City options'));



        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * Make a show builder.
     *
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return Show
     */
    protected function detail($id)
    {
        $show = new Show(City::findOrFail($id));



        return $show;
    }

    /**
     * Make a form builder.
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function form()
    {
        $form = new Form(new City());

      //  $form->select('country_id', __("Category"))->options((new City())::selectOptions());

        $form->text('city_name',__('City Name'))->required();

        $form->select('country_id', __('Country Name'))
        ->options(Country::all()->pluck('country_name', 'id'))
        ->rules('required');
        

        $form->text('city_information',__('City information'))->required();

        $form->file('city_video',__('City Video'))->rules('mimes:mp4,')->move('/files/city/city_video_information');
        
        $form->file('city_voice_information',__('Voice information'))->rules('mimes:mp3,')->move('/files/city/city_voice_information');
        
        
        
        $form-> checkbox('city_available_options',__('This city contain'))
        ->options(city_option::all()
        ->pluck('option_name', 'id'))
        ->canCheckAll()->stacked() ;  //
        
        return $form;
    }
}
```

cityOptionsController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Models\city_option;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column;
use Encore\Admin\Controllers\AdminController;
use Encore\Admin\Form;
use Encore\Admin\Grid;
use Encore\Admin\Show;

class CityOptionController extends AdminController
{
    /**
     * Title for current resource.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = 'city_option';

    /**
     * Make a grid builder.
     *
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new city_option());

        $grid->column('option_name',__('Option name'));

        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * Make a show builder.
     *
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return Show
     */
    protected function detail($id)
    {
        $show = new Show(city_option::findOrFail($id));



        return $show;
    }

    /**
     * Make a form builder.
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function form()
    {
        $form = new Form(new city_option());
        $form->text('option_name',__('Option Name'))->required();
        
        


        return $form;
    }
}
```

and thanks

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the error page.

Comment: sorry but how can i find the stack trace

Comment: The stack trace is the whole error message with all the steps in it. It basically explains the path the code took through the application leading up to the error

Comment: SQL has `GROUP_CONCAT()`.